# SQL error on INSERT : "relation does not exists" / but the table is not required

Tags: sql, postgresql, backup, sql-insert

I've got an issue with an INSERT TO statement. Even the most basic one doesn't work :

```
`INSERT INTO` tout.p_sitetech(st_name)
`SELECT` name
`FROM` tout.site_collect
```

It returns :

> *error relation "fond.edi_comm" doesnt exist.*
>
> *LINE 1: ...concat(left(B.id_comm,2),right(B.id_comm,3)) From fond.edi_c...*

But there are **no "fond" schema** in the database (and therefore **no "edi_comm"** table).

The database Im using is a backup, I may have not set it up correctly when restoring. But other `INSERT INTO` work..

It may trigger something in the background ? How do I identify it ?

Thanks in advance for your answers and tips !

Comment: Any views or triggers involved?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Im using PostgreSQL

Answer (score 0):

Execute

```
\d tout.site_collect
```

in `psql` to show the table definition with all its triggers. It must be a trigger or a rule that is defined on the table.

Comment: Thanks. There is indeed a trigger and the issue comes from there. Next step : trying to find how to fix this..